# Объединить 2 строковых столбца и установить индексом в pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Нужно объединить 2 строковых столбца и установить индексом в pandas. Пробовала так:

```
df13['Н'] = df13['Наименование инвестиционного проекта (группы инвестиционных проектов)'].combine(df13['Идентификатор инвестиционного проекта'], np.sum)
```

- не работает.  В датафрейме много столбцов, а сшить надо только 2.

Comment: объединять можно по разному... Можете привести [mcve] данных и результат, который вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pandas.Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html). Примерно так:

```
df13['Н'] = df13['Наименование инвестиционного проекта (группы инвестиционных проектов)'].str.cat(df13['Идентификатор инвестиционного проекта'])
```

Установить индекс:

```
df13.set_index('H')
```

Answer (score 2):

можно установить индекс, не создавая нового столбца:

```
df13.index = \
    df13['Наименование инвестиционного проекта (группы инвестиционных проектов)'] \
    + df13['Идентификатор инвестиционного проекта']
```